# How to properly configure xstartup file for TightVNC with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS GNOME environment

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-12.04, amazon-ec2, tightvnc

I'm trying to configure Gnome-Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I'm able to view the desktop with Real VNC Viewer, Apple VNC Screen Share and other VNC viewers,
I can run my applications, the desktop manager works, copy/paste works within the server,
however, the background is gray (no wallpaper), the icons are missing (e.g. clock, audio, etc.), copy/paste does not work between the client and server, right click doesn't work.

Here's what I installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver xtightvncviewer tightvnc-java
sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
sudo apt-get install metacity
sudo apt-get install light-themes
touch ~/.Xresources
vncpasswd
```

Here's my ~/.vnc/xstartup file:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
#export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:Unity"
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:GNOME"
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"


[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

#dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --debug &
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --builtin --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
#gnome-session --builtin --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
gnome-panel &
#gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

Here's what my screen looks like [image]

Anaconda dbus:

```
  
$ dbus-launch --sh-syntax
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-dnJFV4HI5y,guid=350c8578f2338379a8489f7a5f91b7e8';
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS;
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID=240265;
```

Here's the log file /home/ubuntu/.vnc/ip-10-0-1-82:1.log:

```
22/10/20 16:49:46 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
22/10/20 16:49:46 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
22/10/20 16:49:46 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
22/10/20 16:49:46 All Rights Reserved.
22/10/20 16:49:46 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
22/10/20 16:49:46 Desktop name 'X' (ip-10-0-1-82:1)
22/10/20 16:49:46 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
22/10/20 16:49:46 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
22/10/20 16:49:46 Listening for HTTP connections on TCP port 5801
22/10/20 16:49:46   URL http://ip-10-0-1-82:5801
/home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup: 15: vncconfig: not found
gnome-session-binary[240444]: DEBUG(+): Enabling debugging
gnome-session-binary[240444]: DEBUG(+): hardware acceleration check is disabled
gnome-session-binary[240444]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of QT_IM_MODULE=ibus environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-session-binary[240444]: DEBUG(+): Could not make systemd aware of QT_IM_MODULE=ibus environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-session-binary[240444]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-session-binary[240444]: DEBUG(+): Could not make systemd aware of XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-session-binary[240444]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-session-binary[240444]: DEBUG(+): Could not make systemd aware of GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-session-binary[240444]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome- environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-session-binary[240444]: DEBUG(+): Could not make systemd aware of XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome- environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-session-binary[240444]: DEBUG(+): Finding a graphical session for user 1000
gnome-session-binary[240444]: DEBUG(+): Considering session '45'
gnome-session-binary[240444]: DEBUG(+): Session '45' is not a graphical session (type: 'tty')
gnome-session-binary[240444]: DEBUG(+): Considering session '3'
gnome-session-binary[240444]: DEBUG(+): Session '3' is not a graphical session (type: 'tty')
gnome-session-binary[240444]: WARNING: Could not get session id for session. Check that logind is properly installed and pam_systemd is getting used at login.
gnome-session-binary[240444]: DEBUG(+): Using systemd for session tracking
gnome-session-binary[240444]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
gnome-session-binary[240444]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
metacity-Message: 16:49:47.440: could not find XKB extension.

(metacity:240446): metacity-WARNING **: 16:49:47.446: Failed to create compositor: Missing composite extension required for compositing

(gnome-panel:240445): gnome-panel-WARNING **: 16:49:47.528: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

22/10/20 16:49:51 Got connection from client 104.143.92.196
22/10/20 16:49:51 Using protocol version 3.3
22/10/20 16:49:51 Full-control authentication passed by 104.143.92.196
22/10/20 16:49:51 Using zlib encoding for client 104.143.92.196
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
22/10/20 16:49:51 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 104.143.92.196
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 1104
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 1100
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 1101
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 1105
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 1102
22/10/20 16:49:51 Pixel format for client 104.143.92.196:
22/10/20 16:49:51   32 bpp, depth 32, little endian
22/10/20 16:49:51   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
22/10/20 16:49:51 Using zlib encoding for client 104.143.92.196
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
22/10/20 16:49:51 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 104.143.92.196
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 1104
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 1100
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 1101
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 1105
22/10/20 16:49:51 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 1102
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after removing the Anaconda version of 'dbus'.
The icons are still missing, but this is an issue with 'dbus' and 'gnome-tweaks'.

```
$ conda uninstall dbus
```

[image]